# How to increase email download speed of thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I installed Mozilla Thunderbird 17.0. I configured my email account which has 22,000 emails. Initially, emails were downloaded in bunch of 120 to 125 emails per 'Get Mail' button click. But, from last few days, it downloaded on 2 to 3 emails per 'Get Mail' button click.

How can i increase download speed of the Thunderbird?

Comment: Thunderbird should have been able to download all your emails in a single attempt.   Why were you forced to click `Get Mail` multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a large or spam email stuck in your POP box. Your problem is a common symptom of the client getting mail, hitting a mail it cannot download and stopping. I would suggest logging into the server side of whoever hosts your email (webmail for instance) and delete anything you don't need, then retry the collection via thunderbird.

Comment: I've seen this happen with multiple mail clients. Good advice, though I'm not convinced it's the same problem if @Ozzone keeps getting a few emails in. But worth checking.